# How to use an array of objects on a foundation email template?

Tags: handlebars.js, ejs

Im using foundation emails, i can use variables on a template by wrapping them in a `raw` tag, for example:

```
<raw><%= myVariable %></raw>
```

Now, I need to add attachments,  and attachmeants come as an array with this form:

```
      attachmentsData: [
        {
          id: '301e165f-130e-4f89-83da-a49ff43172ce_Screenshotfrom2018-11-1916-43-01.png',
          title: 'Screenshotfrom2018-11-1916-43-01.png',
          url: 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev-messaging-attachments/301e165f-130e-4f89-83da-a49ff43172ce_Screenshotfrom2018-11-1916-43-01.png',
        },
        {
          id: '301e165f-130e-4f89-83da-a49ff43172ce_Screenshotfrom2018-11-1916-43-02.png',
          title: 'Screenshotfrom2018-11-1916-43-02.png',
          url: 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev-messaging-attachments/301e165f-130e-4f89-83da-a49ff43172ce_Screenshotfrom2018-11-1916-43-02.png',
        },
      ],
```

On the documentation it also says that i can loop over arrays that are declared in `src/data` in yml format.

However in my case i need the array of objects to come from the backend.

but if it comes from the backend it i have to parse it with the `raw` tags.

But if use the raw tags i cant use the `each` helper:
https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/panini.html#custom-data

Do you know how to loop over this array? 
note that, If i do `<raw><%= myArray[0].name %></raw>` this works and prints the right value.

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `<raw><%= myArray[0].name %></raw>` works, then the following should work too.

```
<% myArray.forEach(data => { %>
    <raw><%= data.name %></raw>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: it doesnt work , i get:
 ```Could not find matching close tag for "<%=".

       6 | function renderEmailTemplate(fileName, data) {
       7 |   const template = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../emailTemplates/dist', `${data.locale}_${fileName}`));
    >  8 |   return ejs.render(template.toString(), data);
         |              ^
       9 | }
      10 |
      11 | module.exports = renderEmailTemplate;```
I also tried wrapping everything on a raw tag, but still no luck any other ideas?